# cant get an mp4 video to play in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a really tough time getting an mp4 video to play in a browser window.  I am fairly new to html, and I have been doing a lot of research on trying to figure out why it is not working.  Right now it is just giving me a blank video player  Here is the code that I have

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
               ready: function () {
                   $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                       m4v: "/videos/m4v/sequence01mp4video_480x270_h264aac.m4v",
                       ogv: "/videos/ogv/sequence01mp4video_480x270.ogv",
                       png: "/videos/png/sequence01_480x270.png"
                   });
               },
               swfPath: "/javascripts",
               supplied: "m4v, ogv"
           });
       });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-video ">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
      <div class="jp-gui">
        <div class="jp-video-play">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="jp-video-play-icon" tabindex="1">play</a>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-interface">
          <div class="jp-progress">
            <div class="jp-seek-bar">
              <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <div class="jp-controls-holder">
            <ul class="jp-controls">
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
              <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="jp-toggles">
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-full-screen" tabindex="1" title="full screen">full screen</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-restore-screen" tabindex="1" title="restore screen">restore screen</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
              <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-no-solution">
        <span>Update Required</span>
        To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest an alternative to your current Javascript setup?

Try Video.js, a lightweight HTML5 video player.

http://videojs.com/#section5